# The @Resources.STR inside <!-- --> comment in a cshtml file is still needed or not?

Tags: c#, razor

When I removed the string in resources file, the webpage reports a error saying this string is not found.
But this @Resources.STR is inside a  comment in a cshtml file, why would it be needed? 
I'm new to cshtml and I feel confused about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<!-- -->` are HTML comments. The server does execute code listed within such comments, and sends the result to the client. The client just doesn't display them. You can see this by clicking View Source in your browser or inspecting the HTTP traffic.

Use `@* *@` for serverside comments which will not be rendered by the server and not be sent to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found an Ugly way of doing this, if you separate the elements for the comment like:

> @{   < text><< /text>< text>!--< /text>
>       Your razor code here   < text>-->< /text> }

For me as a newbie it worked to place just the start of a comment based on a if statement :D